# manipulation of String in the output

Tags: java, string

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Vowel
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String myString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your text: ");
        char[] cArray = myString.trim().toCharArray();
        if(cArray.length == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter any text");
            return;
        }
        String vowelLetters = "Vowel Letters: [";
        String notVowelLetters = "Non-Vowel Letters: [";
        int nVowel = 0;
        int nNotVowel = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(isVowel(cArray[i]))
            {
                vowelLetters += "" + cArray[i];
                nVowel++;
                if(i != cArray.length - 1) vowelLetters += ", ";
                continue;
            }
            notVowelLetters += "" + cArray[i];
            nNotVowel++;
            if(i != cArray.length - 1) notVowelLetters += ", ";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your text Contains:\n" + vowelLetters + "] which contains " + nVowel + " Letters\n" + notVowelLetters + "] which contains " + nNotVowel + " Letters");
    }
    public static boolean isVowel(char c)
    {
        return Character.toUpperCase(c) == 'A' || Character.toUpperCase(c) == 'O' ||
               Character.toUpperCase(c) == 'U' || Character.toUpperCase(c) == 'I' ||
               Character.toUpperCase(c) == 'E' ? true : false;
    }
}
```

if I enter, for example, the following text: "abcdef"

the output will be like this:

```
Your text contains:
Vowel Letters: [a, e, ] which contains 2 letters
Non-Vowel Letters: [b, c, d, f] which contains 4 letters
```

As you see, it contains an extra "," in [a, e, ]
I want it to be [a, e]

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: small advice: in isVowel you can change part: return (cond?true:false) to return (cond) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know how many vowels you will have, use this strategy:

```
if (isVowel(cArray[i]))
{
   if (nVowel > 0) vowelLetters += ", ";

   vowelLetters += "" + cArray[i];
   nVowel++;
}
```

The same for the non-vowels.

Comment: I like this strategy, add "," before the letter .. Thanks!